# Polymorphic relationship confusion

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

So I'm confused about how ActiveRecord is handling this, and hoped someone could give me some insight.

I have a table that has a polymorphic relationship.  We'll call it table choices.  In there I have defined:

```
belongs_to :chooseable, polymorphic: true
```

I have two models, let's call one movies, and the other plays.  In there, I have:   `has_many :choices as: chooseable, dependent: destroy`

In the model with the polymorphic relationship I have two scopes:

```
  scope :with_movies, -> {
    includes(:movies)
      .where("chooseable_type": "Measure")
  }
  scope :with_shows, -> {
    includes(:shows)
      .where(shows: { hidden: false })
  }
```

What is confusing to me, is, if I say users.choices.with_movies, and I leave out the chooseable_type where condition, AR balks at me and says:

```
Unknown column 'choices.chooseable_type' in 'where clause': SELECT `movies`.* FROM `movies` WHERE `choices`.`chooseable_type` = 'Movie' AND `movies`.`id` IN (728)
```

Yet, in the second scope with_shows, I don't need to define chooseable_type - it works fine.  The even more confusing thing is, if I remove the where clause, with_shows, doesn't work as well.

I really don't understand why the where clause in the second scope allows a proper query to be generated, yet without it, it falls on its face.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that Rails tries to do it’s best building the resulting complicated query for you, and it resolves

```
.where("chooseable_type": "Measure")
```

to it’s best assumption, which is the main table for this query. Help it to not fail, specify the table name explicitly:

```
.where("movies.chooseable_type": "Measure")
```

Comment: So because the other scope has a where clause for the shows table, it knows to apply the chooseable_type clause to the shows table, even though it doesn't explicitly tell it to?  That's so strange to me.

Comment: Try to `puts with_shows.to_sql` to see the query built.